# Regex pattern for everything after "?>"

Tags: regex

I've been pulling my hair out for hours, but can't seem to get the regex pattern for this.

I have a few hundred files that look like this:
http://pastebin.com/077tdbEW
and am trying to delete everything after "?>" in notepad++

Comment: Can you add some inputs a,expected output and attempts

Comment: [This question is off topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Additionally you need to tag what language you're using the regex in.

Comment: Yes - sure! I would start off with something like: http://pastebin.com/uyqM7afR and would like to end up with: http://pastebin.com/bjnvS9kB

Comment: Search for the "m" modifier of regex, it allows to solve your problem if you are sure you want to go with regex. But for what I'm seeing in that file, you could just read line by line and drop the rest when you find your desired one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=\?>)[\s\S]*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/22